# Количество символов в HTML, в поле типа TEXT, БД PostgreSQL

Tags: html, sql, postgresql

Подскажите, как можно подсчитать количество символов в поле типа TEXT в БД PostgreSQL, подсчитать количество символов без пробелов, HTML-ссылок, спец. символов?

Пример текста поля:

> <p>Каждый месяц в проходят заседания клуба в киноцентре «Рекорд». С 14 по 16 декабря нижегородцев ждет мини-фестиваль клуба «in extremis esse» («на кромке бытия» – лат.). В программе мероприятия 6 фильмов, 7 творческих встреч с кинорежиссерами – создателями фильмов, 6 острых социальных проблем.</p>

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете узнать длину строки, убрав все ненужные символы регулярным
выражением.  Пример для латинского текста:

```sql
SELECT length(regexp_replace('Hello world!', '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g'));
-- Output:
--
--   length 
--  --------
--       10
--  (1 row)
```

---

Для того, чтобы эффективно работать с *HTML*, вам нужен полный
*HTML*-парсер, которого в *SQL* нет.  Вариант хуже и проще:

```sql
SELECT length(
         regexp_replace(
           regexp_replace('<p>Hello world!</p>', '<.*?>', '', 'g')
         , '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g'
         )
       )
;
-- Output:
--
--   length 
--  --------
--       10
--  (1 row)
```

Comment: Я бы на всякий случай обернул в COALESCE - мало ли что там в таблице... впрочем да, показанному примеру это не нужно.

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что текст хранится в формате HTML, с возможными div, p, src, как-то можно преобразовать в простой текст и подсчитать количество символов с латиницей и русским

Comment: @SergeyKir  См. правку.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы, решил проблему другим путем, на стороне PHP вычисляю количество символов. а потом просто заполняю в таблице поле со значением, так не нужно HTML парсинам на стороне sql  заморачиваться.